# Google Cloud SQL Grant - mysql.proc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When executing a procedure in Google CloudSQL it throws error -

> User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored
>   procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure
>   connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver
>   generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of
>   actual parameter types

So check stackover flow and found solution like to execute query

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'stutzen.co'@'%';
```

But Cloud SQL throws error for it

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation

Is there any way to solve this problem in CloudSQL? Why it is stopping to execute even a simple procedure?